# How to overload a built-in vb.net function

Tags: vb.net, overriding, overloading

I want to overload the built in `MsgBox()` function in VB.Net.

I want to add a beep every time a MsgBox pops up, but would rather not make a new function, e.g., `MsgBoxWithBeep()`, and do a whole bunch of find/replace in my existing code.

I can do this just fine within a module:

```
Public Sub MsgBox(msg As String)
    Beep()
    MsgBox(msg)
End Sub
```

But of course this ends up being an endless recursive loop.

I can't do `MyBase.MsgBox()` because this is not a class.

Is there an assumed class that all built-in function use like so I can do something like `VbNetBaseClass.MsgBox()` or some other way to get back to the original function?.

Comment: There are several such things, MsgBox comes from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction` but it is a module, not a class.  However overloading means to give it a different signature.  This is required so the compiler knows which version to call - your "new" MsgBox method fits the standard signature (which has several optional params) which is a problem.  The easiest thing is to write a wrapper.

Comment: @Plutonix: That works as well ! The only thing that puts `MessageBox()` ahead of `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox()` is the built-in beep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to just use MsgBox to call MessageBox.Show like this:

```
Public Sub MsgBox(msg As String)
    Beep()
    MessageBox.Show(msg, Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK)
End Sub
```

Or better yet, use the exclamation/error icons that already make a beep:

```
Public Sub MsgBox(msg As String)
    MessageBox.Show(msg, Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Sub
```

_

> Edit: good point from blackwood...you can make it into a function if you need the result:

```
Public Function MsgBox(msg As String, _
                       Optional title As String = "", _
                       Optional msgButtons As MessageBoxButtons = MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                       Optional msgIcon As MessageBoxIcon = MessageBoxIcon.None) _
                   As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult
    Return MessageBox.Show(msg, title, msgButtons, msgIcon)
End Function
```

Comment: As `MsgBox` is a function that returns a `MsgBoxResult` value, you should probably change the Sub in your example to a function and return the appropriate value based on what `MessageBox` returns.

Comment: I fear @rion-williams is probably right about overriding/overloading non-class based functions. However, there is an exception with 'MsgBox()' thanks to the fact that there are two functions that do the same thing - `MsgBox()` and `MessageBox.Show()`. And you can also call the original function via its "class": `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you'll be able to override or overload the `MsgBox()` method as it is `static` and a standard module (as opposed to a class) [as seen here within the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Microsoft/VisualBasic/Interaction.cs,8a2fa8bfa51571c8) :

```
[StandardModule]
public sealed class Interaction
{
    /* Other methods omitted for brevity */

    public static MsgBoxResult MsgBox(object Prompt, MsgBoxStyle Buttons = MsgBoxStyle.ApplicationModal, object Title = null);
}
```

Your best bet is going to be to write your own method or wrapper to handle calling it with your optional overloads, etc.